# Patch route gives 404, even when the route is defined and exists

Tags: laravel-5.1, laravel-routing

I have this route for edit and update

```
//Designation Details for Staffs
Route::get('designation/{staffid}', array(
  'as' => 'designation.edit',
  'uses'=>'StaffController@editDesignation'));
Route::patch('designation/update/{staffid}', array(
  'as' => 'designation.update',
  'uses'=>'StaffController@updateDesignation'));
```

The `edit` Route is working fine with the form model as:

```
{!! Form::model($designation, [
        'method' => 'PATCH',
        'route' => ['designation.update', $designation->staffid]
        ]) !!}
```

But, when the Submit button is clicked for `update`, it has the url

```
http://localhost/hrm/public/designation/update/2
```

and leads to `404`. Just letting you know, all other routes are working fine. For similar case, another update route:

```
Route::patch('staff/update/{id}', array(
  'as' => 'staff.update',
  'uses'=>'StaffController@update'));
```

is working fine as well. TIA.

**UPDATE**: Controller Method `updateDesignation`

```
public function updateDesignation($staffid, Request $request){
        /*
            ** Update for Staff's Designation Information
        */
        $designation= Designation::findOrFail($staffid);

        $input = $request->all();
        //dd($input);

        $designation->fill($input)->save();    

        return view('staff.editdesignation')->with('designation',$designation)->with('staffid',$staffid);

    }
```

Comment: Please set the updateDesignation code

Comment: @BKF I have updated the question. You can see the controller method there.

Comment: Have you set staff.editdesignation route ?

Comment: @BKF that's not route, that's view path.

Comment: Yes yes I mean the blade

Answer (score 1):

Use can use put instead of patch. Html form doesn't support put, patch or delete  options. So add a hidden _method field to the form.

Answer (score 1):

There was a mistake on my Query

```
$designation= Designation::findOrFail($staffid);
```

`$staffid` was not a Primary Key but a Foreign key. I solved it by changing my query to.

```
$designation = Designation::where('staffid', $staffid)->firstOrFail();
```

Comment: yes the findOrFail throws a 404 error automatically.

Comment: @Gokigooooks Not all the time, if the parameter passed it primary key, it is always good.

Comment: Yeah but there are no matching records it will throw a 404 error